# Wordpress address URL and bloginfo

Tags: css, urls, https, bloginfo

I have updated my Wordpress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) to be https:// in the General Settings of Wordpress as I have added a secruity certificate to the hosting.

Should the css url automatically update to reflect the new address if I'm using

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
```

in the header code.

The url is now https:// but the css url is still pointint to http://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `site_url($path_to_style_sheet, 'https')` instead of `bloginfo()`.

The `home_url()` method also supports https.